# Lucene can't find documents after update

Tags: java, lucene

It seems that whenever I update an existing document in the index (same behavior for delete / add), it can't be found with a TermQuery. Here's a short snippet:

iw = new IndexWriter(directory, config);

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new StringField("string", "a", Store.YES));
doc.add(new IntField("int", 1, Store.YES));

iw.addDocument(doc);

Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("string","a"));

Document[] hits = search(query);
doc = hits[0];
print(doc);

doc.removeField("int");
doc.add(new IntField("int", 2, Store.YES));

iw.updateDocument(new Term("string","a"), doc);

hits = search(query);
System.out.println(hits.length);
System.out.println("_________________");

for(Document hit : search(new MatchAllDocsQuery())){
    print(hit);
}
```

This produces the following console output:

```
stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<string:a>
stored<int:1>
________________
0
_________________
stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<string:a>
stored<int:2>
________________
```

It seems that after the update, the document (rather the new document) in the index and gets returned by the MatchAllDocsQuery, but can't be found by a TermQuery.

Full sample code available at http://pastebin.com/sP2Vav9v

Also, this only happens (second search not working) when the StringField value contains special characters (e.g. file:/F:/).

Comment: Are you not missing `iw.commit()` ?

Comment: Doesn't change anything. Tried it aleady. Also, the search opens a new reader from the writer each time:   DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(iw, true);

Comment: I seem to be hitting a similar problem. Which version of Lucene is this?

Comment: Tried it with a number of versions between 4_6 and 4_10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code which you have referenced in pastebin doesn't find anything because your `StringField` is nothing but a stopword (`a`). Replacing `a` with something which is not a stopword (e.g. `ax`) makes both searches to return 1 doc.

You would also achieve the correct result if you were to construct `StandardAnalyzer` with empty stopword set (`CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET`) yet still using `a` for `StringField`. This wouldn't work for `file:/F:/` though.

However, the best solution is this case would be to replace `StandardAnalyzer` with `KeywordAnalyzer`.

Comment: I thought StringField isn't being Analyzed? Also, how comes updating has this effect, but inserting a new document doesn't?

Comment: `StringField` isn't analyzed, that's correct. But stopword filter is still applied - see `StandardAnalyzer` Javadoc. Lucene in Action book (page 120-121) says: "`StandardAnalyzer` also includes stopword removal". Regarding updating/inserting question -- I'm not entirely sure. I'll try to debug and post results if I find any.

Answer (score 1):

I could get rid of this by recreating my working directory after all indexing operations :
create a new directory just for this indexing operations named "path_dir" for example. If you have updated then call the following operations and do all of your  previous works again.

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46);
FSDirectory dir;
try {
    // delete indexing files :
    dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(path_dir));
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_46, analyzer);
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);
    writer.deleteAll();
    writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, note that this way will be very slow if you are handling big data.

Comment: How is this exactly a "fix"? Deleting the index is absolutely ridiculous! What happens if you need to update 10 000 000 records five times and you have to delete the index each time?! This is not acceptable.

Comment: I have already commented about big data at the end of my answer. I could make my code works fine in this way. Since I'm not handling big data, it was not a problem for me.If michael also have small data it might work.